# How to get more gpu memory in slurm

Tags: gpu, slurm

I'm working in a linux server and get a problem to get more GPU memory.

[image]

I set parameters of --mem, --mem-per-gpu, but when i check using nvidia-smi, the gpu memory is always not over 3G.
So, I want to know how to get more GPU memory to speed up my code, thank you.

Comment: What are you doing? Machine learning? using what Tensorflow or Pytorch?

Comment: yes, it's machine learning, specific, deep learning, I train my neural network in server, and using the Pytorch. I want to have more GPU memory to speed up and decrease the running time.

Comment: Noooooo. more GPU VRAM consumption does not mean more speed unless your model is configure to run in parallel across multiple GPUs. VRAM's consumption size depends on the tensors. If you use a bigger dataset or a bigger architecture you will use more VRAM. This has nothing to do with speed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation. I'm a little confused.  So, when I used google colab, it's 16G gpu, the time of each epoch training is about 70 second. With the same code, the time spend in server is more than 10 minutes, and when I connect to the node and check with nvidia-smi, it shows the figure in above. So, I'm confused and don't know the reason. And how can I do to speed up the running, using the parallel training, right? Thank you

Comment: It depends on many factors. May be the hardware is older compared to what you were using on the Colab. May be the Python version and its libraries are different. But the difference is significant. A 70 sec per epoch model on Colab is very small one. It shouldn't take even 5 minutes on CPU.

Comment: A manual for parallel training: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's very helpful of your suggestion, maybe I need to reexam my code carefully, thank you very much.